# Why is this Isinstance function not working?

Tags: python, isinstance

This does not print anything for some reason.

---

```
main = 60

x = isinstance(main, int)

if x == ("True"):  
   print("True") 

elif x == ("False"):  
   print("False")
```

---

Comment: `x` is not `("True")` or `("False")` it's `True` or `False`

Comment: Yes, you're comparing a bool and a string, note that the parentheses do not create a tuple here in the absence of a comma, although they do reduce clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boolean value which is returned by the `isinstance()` function is not a string, but (as you may been able to guess) a boolean.

To rewrite the code provided:

```py
main = 60
x = isinstance(main, int)
if x is True:
    print("True")
elif x is False:
    print("False")
```

However, since booleans can be conditions themselves, and `isinstance()` returns a boolean, I would recommend this approach:

```py
main = 60
if isinstance(main, int):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Alternatively, even simpler:

```py
main = 60
print(isinstance(main, int))
```